# Admin form for django-autocomplete-light

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use the django-autocomplete-light to add some nice autocomplete features to a Django Admin form. (DAL certainly seems to be the best/most popular and seems to have a lot of great features, it is a shame the docs are so poorly structured).

The autocomplete field does not get created if I create an admin form like this:

```
@admin.register(RaffleTicket)
class RaffleTicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RaffleTicket
    code = forms.IntegerField()
    bought_by = autocomplete_light.ModelChoiceField('PersonAutocomplete')
```

But it works if I create a plain `ModelForm` (which I never use anywhere else) and shove it directly into my `ModelAdmin`, like so:

```
class RaffleTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code = forms.IntegerField()
    bought_by = autocomplete_light.ModelChoiceField('PersonAutocomplete')


@admin.register(RaffleTicket)
class RaffleTicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RaffleTicket
    form = RaffleTicketForm
```

Why is it so? And is there a better way (i.e. single class definition) to do this than what I have found?

Answer (score 0):

The first code doesn't work because it sets form fields in the modeladmin class, which has no reason to work at all, you haven't seen that in any documentation, ever.

Did you try just this ?

```
@admin.register(RaffleTicket)
class RaffleTicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = RaffleTicket
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(RaffleTicket)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, my form here should have fields = ('code', 'bought_by') and I should have defined the Model class. Anyway, I gave up with DAL and used the django-select2 library instead.

Comment: We're going to break down DAL into smaller apps and make it compatible with django-select2 and the likes (so that you can have security even with django-select2 ;))